# Upgrading to jquery 1.5 leads to issues with .getJSON

Tags: jquery, getjson, jquery-1.5

I have a part of my present code as follows:

$.getJSON("http://cross.subdomain.url.com",
           function (data) {
                               alert(data.someobj); 
                               //use the data to do some work.
                           }
          );

The url http://cross.subdomain.url.com, returns json.

This was working perfectly fine , when in jquery 1.4.4.

After updating to jquery 1.5, this has stopped working.

I have tried the following variations of the same:

1. Changing dataType to json.
2. Adding "callback?" to the query.

Can someone please shed light on how the jquery ajax object behaves??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is also occurring when on the server side the content type is not set to json.
On the server side doing the following resolves the issue:

1. response.setContenyType("text/json");
2. response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply your data as JSONP.

This is JSON, wrapped in a function, so rather than returning `{"happy":"yes"}` on the server side, in response to a request for a url containing the query string parameter `callback=myfunction`, you generate `myfunction({"happy":"yes"})` as the response.

This may have been masked in a prior version of Jquery and your application could have not worked in some browsers (eg. Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and it is fixed in 1.5.1. See ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8125, You can find the latest jQuery release with up to date fixes at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js

Comment: the bug talks about having links to local files.Isint that different from having links to other subdomains??

Comment: I got the nightly build from git, and tried that out.Same issue.

Comment: @Neeraj I had the same problem as yours and that's how i solved it. No reason for the code to work in 1.4.4 and not in 1.5 unless it's the bug i referred you to. You can open a bug ticket at jQuery.com to verify this issue. They Reply pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery documentation page for [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) reveals the following (in the *[Additional Notes](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#notes-0)* section):

> Due to browser security restrictions,
>   most "Ajax" requests are subject to
>   the same origin policy; the request
>   can not successfully retrieve data
>   from a different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol.

It sounds like you are violating that policy.